# What is the methodology to discover thousands of compounds from a complex mixture?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, food-chemistry

So this is something that has always amazed me,

---

> More than 1,000 chemical compounds in coffee,[1] and their molecular and physiological effects, are areas of active research in food chemistry.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_coffee_chemicals

---

How is it possible to identify so many separate compounds from just a single matter? What methods are used?

Comment: Sorry to interrupt the row. Just to answer the original question: mostly chromatography. Concerning the (somewhat off-topic, isn't it?) discussion above, yes, a scientist will indeed use intuition from time to time, but the final answer will always come from rational observation and reproducible methods. You may 'think' that coffee does not contain thousands of chemicals, but if you put it through GCMS, LCMS, etc, and find thousands of different peaks, well, unfortunately you can't but accept that you were wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most compounds can only be analytically quantified *individually*, so the first step in analyzing a complex mixture is typically to separated the different compounds from each other. For something like coffee, this would typically be done via different types of [chromatography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatography) (i.e. gas (GC), liquid (HPLC), ion (IC)).

As the separated compounds exit the chromatography column, they can then be analyzed. This is usually done in real time using a number of techniques; the most relevant in this case is [mass spectrometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_spectrometry) (MS) following GC or HPLC.

In short, the primary techniques used to analyzed the compounds found in an organic sample like coffee would be GC-MS and HPLC-MS.

Comment: +1 Add a large database to identify your mass spectra.